# How to wrap web app to windows 10 desktop app?

Tags: windows, webview, wrapper

I have a web application (accessed by clients using standard browser) which is available on custom individual url for each client and I would like to "generate" a "custom desktop application" (probably zip file with some exe file and some xml config file - where exe runs webview with url from xml) which can be installed on clients computer (Windows 10 support only is ok). This application when launched will open frameless window (no menu, no url bar etc) of a custom size with webview opening the defined https url (url will contain secret login hash for user / or session must be kept even after computer restart etc ..). This app should run only online (no offline mode needed).

The goal is to take one simple specific proces (entering simple data) from a complex web application and make this simple process easilly accessible for users (just click icon and enter data, submit to server, close, no login ever needed).

I have no experience developing for Windows 10, but I expect there must be some easy "universal app" solution as probably more developers are solving the same problem. What are the most (time) effective, but standard and safe possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice tutorial: https://www.todesktop.com/guides/nativefier. This tool is based on Node.js, which works fine on macOS, Windows, or Linux.

First, install Node.js on your computer. Then, run

```
npm i nativefier -g
```

to install nativefier. You can wrap your web app into native app simply by running

```
nativefier "your-url" --name "Application Name"
```

You can read the post for further information, like code signing your application, generating native installers, etc.

Comment: Tutorial link not working anymore